# how convers String to object in java by method getter

Tags: java

how i write body for the method in java:

getExpression(String strExp): Expressiongit 
-converts a valid String expression
strExp into an Expression object and returns it.

Comment: your question is ambiguous

Answer (score -1):

FYI a String is an Object ...
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: How does this answer the question (whatever the question actually is)?

Comment: the page does not exist or is no longer available.